# Sync multiple calendar together

Tags: icloud, calendar, google-calendar, network

Simple question, big problem. I evaluate a solution to sync calendar together but not FULL calendar.. just part with cloud here is the spec : I have 3 person

- person #1 = have a calendar with personal, professional, account, prospect
- person #2 = have company and personal
- person #3 = have company, internal, account

now, i like to be able to share personal calendar between person 1 and 2, company between person 2 and 3 and account between person 1 and 3... all the rest should be absolutely private !

I have research.. and i cloud and i cal share ALL and you HIDE some color in the calendar... that's NOT what i want... hide is not private...

so my research get me to : Google calendar with busy sync or [BusyCal](http://www.busymac.com/busycal/index.html) wich is an application that do the sync (i think !)

You guy's do you have solution, what have you try and what work ?

thanks in advance

Comment: It seems to be like either iCloud or Google Calendar will give you this functionality.  If you want to share a specific calendar with on or more persons, you simply enter their account email addresses to set it up.  Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Yes but sharing share everything... private and not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use BusySync... overall it works well.  It certainly accomplishes exactly what you're talking about.  I have several thousand events on my calendar, which appears to corrupt the database from time to time, as I have BusySync conflict issues, as they're called.  These errors are rare, and support from the company has always been a) speedy, b) comprehensive, c) able to solve the issue. I spent a substantial amount of time researching this years ago, well before iCloud and BusyMac were available... but at that time, BusySync was the only reasonable choice.  Since then, I haven't switched, because this solution still works well.

I recommend BusySync or BusyMac... both work the same way, it just depends which environment you prefer.

While you could use BusySync to host on a local server and that would be fine, working through Google is easy, free, and compatible (you can sync with other machines that don't use iCal or BusySync).  Google also allows for an easy web interface on the go, mobile integration, etc.

I hope that helps.